# Generic Modal Close Icon Being Replaced with Y Shaped Icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, icons

Over the years we've all grown accustomed to closing programs, windows and modal windows by clicking an X at the top right corner of whatever we're trying to close. So I've been surprised to see more frequent use of a Y shaped close icon used in Bootstrap for dismissing content like modals and alerts.

Here's what the icon looks like on my computer using bootstrap:
[image]

It wasn't until I started writing this question however that I realised it was something **specific to my computer**, maybe a font? However when I 'inspect element' it's not clear what the font is that's being used. Does anyone know how I can stop this and make the default X shaped close icon appear instead?

Here's the source code on the Bootstrap demo:

```
<button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
```

Comment: That's odd. Do you have a URL for the page that generates that?

Comment: @msw Yes here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#misc see under 'Close Icon' - but I'm sure you won't be able to see my problem, you'll probably just see a 'x'.

Comment: I do see a properly rendered Helvetica Neue × as you expected. I did want to see the CSS rule that was generating the font-family which "inspect element" shows to come from bootstrap.css line 1064 for tag "button". You've probably got a corrupted font.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to keep going down the font route to find the answer.